# Gathering the highest value where there are multiple system references

Tags: sql

I am trying to determine the highest value of a column where there is three of the same reference.

```
XX_sys_ref  XX_sin_no
1320679         1
1320679         2
1320679         3
```

So far I've tried to use a MAX statement but realised this would only gather the maximum of all of the XX_sin_no (there are 600 system refs I am looking at)

```
select xx_sin_no from xx_durations
where (xx_sin_no) in (select xx_sin_no, max(xx_sin_no)
from xx_durations group by xx_sin_no)
```

This has been stripped down to to show what has been tried so far. I felt it unnecessary to show the MAX statement.

Comment: Your question says "two" but your data has 3 rows with the same reference.  You also mention the highest value of a column.  Which column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff cheers, amended

Comment: I dont really understand what are you looking for.
Do you need the highest value of sin_no for your sys_ref?

Comment: @KeeyPee the sin_no, I'm trying to determine the greatest value in sin_no based off the sys_ref

Comment: posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table:

```
sys_ref sin_no
123       1
123       2
123       3
321       3
321       4
321       5
```

Statement:

```
select sys_ref, max(sin_no) from test_stack group by sys_ref;
```

Result:

```
sys_ref max(sin_no)
123       3
321       5
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select XX_sys_ref,max(xx_sin_no) 
from xx_durations group by XX_sys_ref;
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31ad94/2